# Esri Javascript 4.6 Javascript /Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, service, area, esri

I would like to implement the service Area in Javascript or Angular 2+. But the problem is the only doc I found about it, is a deprecated version (in 3.23). 
I would like to implement it in 4.6 to be updated. 
Some body know how to do it ?

Thanks ! 
(Link deprecated I found https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=routetask_basic_servicearea )

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS API for JavaScript version 3.23 is the newest version of the API 3, and it does not depreciate.

The API 3 comes with full-featured for 2D web map, you better use it if you do nothing about 3D web map.